# Run shell script from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, bash, shell, shebang

I'm trying to run a shell script that is in an `NSTextView`. I know I can use `NSTask` to do this, but I was wondering what the best way would be, if the script only exists in memory (the text view) but not on disk.

Should I temporarily write it to disk or somehow run it directly as string?

And what parameters do I pass to `NSTask`? Do I have to extract the shebang line and pass it as `launchPath`?

Comment: You can pass the parameters using a NSArray, see the setArguments method (or directly use launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute `/bin/bash` as your `NSTask`, and `setStandardInput` to an `NSPipe`.  Then write the `NSString` containing your script to the pipe via its `fileHandleForWriting` to avoid creating a file on disk.

Comment: does the NSSString has to be UTF-8 encoded? NSFileHandleForWriting takes an NSData.